# How can I set up email (mostly yahoo) so that no matter which device I delete an email on, it will be deleted on the other?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, email, k9-mail

I finally switched to Android from Apple, and I've tried setting the email account as both premium and not, and it either stays independent when deleted (not deleted on the server), or it's just downloaded again. K-9 seems to make them stay independent, but there's a lot of settings. Is there anything I can do so that if I delete a message on either the mail site or the app, it will be deleted on the other?

Basically, if you're aware of how the mail app works on the iphone, etc, I want it to behave like that.

EDIT: I found out how to do it in K-9 (change the 'when i delete a message' setting), but is there a way to do it stock?

Comment: Use IMAP instead of POP.

Comment: @roxan: that should be an answer; OP: your email client is configured using POP, which is just a glorified message downloader; if using IMAP instead, deleting, reading/unreading, changing folders, etc will be automatically synchronized to the server across multiple devices. The stock Android Email client and K9 supports both POP and IMAP. IIRC, Yahoo Mail does not support IMAP for free account, so you'd either have to get the paid one or use the official Yahoo! Mail Android client (not stock Email or K9), which does provide an IMAP-like experience.

Answer (score 4):

As roxan already pointed out: **What you want is IMAP for all your E-Mail accounts, configured with an Android client (e.g. K-9 Mail).**

Answer (score 3):

You can simply download [Yahoo! Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail) and manage your e-mail as you want.